# advice with webforms and global functions

Tags: asp.net, webforms

i am new to webforms and come from a php background.

when creating complex web apps in php i usually have a lot of global functions in an includes file. these functions are then made available to other php pages.

how do you implement this in asp.net webforms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is undesirable in Object-Oriented Programming in general. Your global functions probably implement a large number of unrelated features. Instead, relate those features using classes. Put all the functions that implement a particular feature into a single class. You can then make the functions `static` if you like, so they can be referenced as `ClassName.Function`.

Comment: hi john, thanks for the reply...i assume these "classes" are compliled into a DLL and placed in the /Bin folder or am i wrong?

Comment: @Paul: they would be part of your web application, so would be compiled into the same dll. Or you could create a separate class library project and reference it in your web application. Then they would be compiled into a dll and placed into the bin directory for you.

Comment: I would advice against using web forms for new projects since it's sort of deprecated. As I understand it, it will continue to be supported as long as the OS supports full .net framework, but we don't know for how long that will be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Like John said, put your functions into objects.  In general it's best to avoid public static functions when possible for a variety of reasons, especially if you wish to use dependency injection or mocking for tests.

Global data is almost always a warning sign that you could have a problem with your design - so if you're unable to put your methods into objects you might want to look at why.